# Кеширование в Django

Tags: python, django

Не получается закешировать данные.
Делаю так (**ctype.id=158**, **objects=[данные в QuerySet формате]**):

```
from django.core.cache import cache

cached_objects = cache.get('top_rating_%s'%ctype.id)   #вынимаем из кеша
if cached_objects is None:  #Если кеш пуст, то...
  #Тут манипуляция данными

  cache.set('top_rating_%s'%ctype.id, objects, time=1800)  #Кладем в кеш значение objects
  return objects #Возвращаем objects

else:

  return cached_objects #Возвращаем значение из кеша
```

Пробовал перевести данные из типа QuerySet в list:

```
...

objects = list(objects) #Преобразую
cache.set('top_rating_%s'%ctype.id, objects, time=1800) #Кладу в кеш
...
```

В обоих случаях в кеш ничего не сохранялось.
Для проверки пробовал просто положить в кеш строку, все отлично сработало, в кеше значение прожило ровно столько, сколько указал во времени жизни.

Answer (score 2):

Кеш он глупый, умеет хранить только базовые типы данных. Поэтому сложные структуры которые зависят от классов или типов указанных в приложении нужно сериализовать перед записью в кеш и десериализовать после.

[Сериализация объектов в Django](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/topics/serialization/)

Также можно воспользоваться модулем [pickle](http://docs.python.org/library/pickle.html)

Comment: Увы пока не попробую не могу принять как правильное, но бегло глянул, очень похоже на правду. Спасибо за направление.

Answer (score 1):

Видимо, все зависит от бэкенда, т.к. за сериализацию данных каждый бэкенд отвечает сам.

К примеру, с memcache, приведенный выше код, должен работать, т.к. memcache не скалярные данные сериализует при помощи pickle.

UPD. Проверил на django 1.3, python 2.7 - все бэкенды используемые в django автоматически сериализируют объекты, т.ч., видимо, у вас где-то ошибка.

Comment: У меня Django 1.2 и Python 2.5 может в этом дело и эта Django не поддерживает авто сериализацию, тогда придется делать как выше **Antik** описал.